# Spiral matrix(as 2d pointer)

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, spiral

I have a matrix (2d pointer, (**a)) and i want to scan the elements spiral-like.(first rown then last column,last line(reversed),first column,second line, so on.
Ex:

```
1 2 3
8 9 4
7 6 5
```

i have the following code in C but i know im wrong in the "else" condition .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(void)
{
int i, j, n, m, p, q, **a, s, c = 0;
printf("rows\n");
scanf("%d", &m);
printf("cols\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
a = (int**)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    a[i] = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
}
printf("insert\n");
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("a[%d][%d]=", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (j = i+1; j < m-i;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", a[j][m-c]);
        }
        c++;
    }
}


   printf("matrix\n\n");
     for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
     {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
     }
   }
```

Comment: C++ is not C is not C++! Don't add unrealted tags. And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: I didn't follow your entire code, but at a first glance it seems that you're never doing any `j--`. How do you expect it, for the last line in your example, to print `5 6 7`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way could be using a variable `direction`, which could be either east, south, west, north. Denoting them by `0-3`, now we proceed.

Also, we use two auxiliary arrays,

```
int xDir = [0, 1, 0, -1];
int yDir = [1, 0, -1, 0];
```

Starting with `direction = 0`. Every time you are done traversing in a certain direction, you will set `direction = (direction + 1) % 4`.

We will also use another variable `length`, which will denote how far in a certain direction I should travel. Initially `length = row size of your matrix`.

The value of length will be like `row, col - 1, row - 1, col - 2, row - 2, col - 3...`, and this pattern will continue.

When you are done traversing the first row, set `direction` to 1, and update length to the next value of the pattern mentioned above. How you will know you're done? When length step has been completed.

You stop when length value is `0` to begin with.

How you take the next step?

If your current position is `(x,y)`, your next position will be `(x + xDir[direction], y + yDir[direction])`.

For starter, I guess it would help you correct your procedure.